# barh plot fails with "ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'width' must be length 2 or scalar"

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want to have 4 plots in a row, so I tried to insert `ax` into a `list` and loop through the list. Each subplot should look like the plot of:

```
df.plot(kind="barh")
```

However, the following code doesn't work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2],'b': [3, 4]})
df.index = ["Row1", "Row2"]

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 4, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 4, 2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1, 4, 3)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(1, 4, 4)

axis_list = [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]

for ax in axis_list:
    ax.barh(df, kind='barh', width=0.8, colormap='Set1')
```

It fails with this exception:

> ValueError:  incompatible sizes: argument 'width' must be length 2 or scalar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of axes using the **plt.subplots** command, which will tidy up your code. Also note that you can use **df.plot** and specify the axis on which to plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2],'b': [3, 4]})
df.index = ["Row1", "Row2"]

fig, axis_list = plt.subplots(1,4)
for ax in axis_list:
    df.plot(kind='barh',ax=ax,width=0.8, colormap='Set1')
fig.show()
```

[image]